# Como colocar favicon em pagina xml?

Tags: favicon

Como coloco fav icon numa pagina xml?
Como existe no html gostaria de fazer o mesmo numa página xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa colocar o seu arquivo `favicon.ico` na pasta onde está o seu arquivo `.xml`.

Não esquece de limpar o cache sempre para testar

Comment: Nem precisei de escrever codigo bahh